# Membership testing on set of pairs, how do i make the order of element in pairs irrelevant?

Tags: python, python-3.x, set

Here is what I want to do:

```
m1 = (a,b)
m2 = (c,d)
bad_combos = set()
bad_combos.add((m1,m2)) #((a,b),(c,d))
... #adding many other elements in the set

#when i do this:
if (m2,m1) in bad_combos:
    print("Found")
else:
    print("Not Found")

#the result is always "Not Found"
```

Is there a way that I can make the order of elements in a pair irrelevant so when O do the membership testing:

```
bad_combos.add((m3,m4))

if (m4,m3) in bad_combos:

   #This will return True?
```

Any Idea will be greatly appreciated!
Thanks in Advance!

Comment: if order is not important, you may want to use a `set` instead of a `tuple` (pair)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option you have (if `bad_combos` *must stay* a set)  is adding `frozenset`s to your set and then checking if a frozenset of the pairs exists:

```
m1 = ('a','b')
m2 = ('c','d')
bad_combos = set()
bad_combos.add(frozenset([m1,m2])) 

(m2, m1) in bad_combos  # False

frozenset([m2, m1]) in bad_combos  # True
```

this, of course, retains the O(1) complexity for membership testing.

Another option (if sets aren't mandatory) involves you switching to a list as your storing data structure and adding set pairs to it:

```
m1 = ('a','b')
m2 = ('c','d')
bad_combos = []
bad_combos.append({m1,m2}) #((a,b),(c,d))

if {m2,m1} in bad_combos:
    print("Found")
else:
    print("Not Found")
```

this, of course, results in O(n) membership testing.

Comment: So will the cost of membership test in `frozenset` be same as the one in    `set` which is always O(1)? Or is there any performance difference between the two?

Comment: @Han you are still using a set (in the second scenario), you're just adding frozensets to it (which are immutable sets) as opposed to tuples :-). Membership is still `O(1)`.

Comment: Thank you very much! @Jim Fasarakis Hilliard

Answer (score 4):

In general, use `set` instead of `tuple` when order does not matter.

However, you cannot add a set to another set. In this case, you can use `frozenset`:

```python
m1 = (a, b)
m2 = (c, d) # m1 and m2 are tuples

bad_combos = set()
bad_combos.add(frozenset({m1,m2})) # {m1,m2} is a set
# ...
if frozenset({m2,m1}) in bad_combos:
    # True
```

Comment: You can't add a mutable collection (a set) to a set. I'm surprised 4 people *didn't* notice this.

Comment: When I try the above code, it gives error:                                        **TypeError: Unhashable type: set** What should I do to fix it? @Phydeaux

Comment: Use a `frozenset`